# What is the genre of "Kiss me (IMSA remix)"?

Tags: identify-this-genre, electronic-music, remix

In the song [Kiss me (IMSA remix)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHZV0U7xOEc), the artists are Mr. Brick, DJ Lapin and Anna Miracles.

Does this really lazy beat have a name?  What genre would this be?

Comment: Are you looking for the genre of this song, or a name for the specific backing track?

Comment: Im looking for the genre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "[deep house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_house)" remix.  Deep house is a dance music genre with a minimalist, electronic influenced sound.  Personally, I think of it as a "lonely," "after midnight" type of sound.

The larger "house" genre of music developed from music played at house parties in Chicago in the early 1980's.  Like disco before it, it is generally considered to have originated in the gay black dance party subculture.

> Deep house is known for complex melody, use of unrelated chromatic chords underlying most sequences, and a soul, ambient, or lounge vibe to the vocals (if any). In the early compositions (1988–89), influences of jazz music were most frequently brought out by using more complex chords than simple triads (7ths, 9ths, 13ths, suspensions, alterations) which are held for many bars and give compositions a slightly dissonant feel.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_house

The main clue I used is that this particular remix is included on several "deep house" compilations on YouTube.

Comment: Great Answer! Is there a sub genre of "deep house" which this song belongs to?